# Tree visualization in Python using just the root node

Tags: python, visualization, graph-visualization

I'm generating a tree using a recursive algorithm. Each node in my tree looks like this:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, attr=None, label=None):
        self.attr = attr
        self.next_attr_vals = {}
        self.label = label
```

`attr` & `label` are strings, and  `next_attr_vals` is a dictionary whose keys point to other nodes of a similar structure.

I have searched through several Python packages and found treevizer, but it throws tons of errors. Is there any Python package that can crawl through (each node) this structure using just the root node and generate a .dot file?

Asking as I found something similar for Golang a while ago and that library works like a charm using a similar structure.

Comment: Networkx package can.

Comment: @jlandercy Thanks so much! Do you happen to know more specific info about the calls/api available?

Comment: Your question is vague (about what you want to achieve and errors you are getting) and is out of scope of SO (packages recommandation). Anyway networkx might be a good candidate because it allows you to iterate over all nodes or edges, it can recognize trees and have dedicated algorithm for that. It also has the ability to draw graph in dot format. So my advise, if you choose to use networkx, read how to create nodes and then render it, the documentation is consistent on those topics. If you are looking for specific help, then first create a [mcve], read [ask] and update your post accordingly.